# Limit exceeded for cluster creation on Azure Kubernetes, where to cleanup?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

I have deleted the old clusters by deleting the resource group completely.
But when I try to create a new cluster, I am getting error as limit exceeded.

As you can see in the below error.

> {"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The template deployment
> 'microsoft.aks-20210803135741' is not valid according to the
> validation procedure. The tracking id is
> '979df053-50fa-4201-9643-5f3029e0b43d'. See inner errors for
> details.","details":[{"code":"QuotaExceeded","message":"Provisioning
> of resource(s) for container service testingdelete in resource group
> testingdelete failed. Message: {\n "code": "QuotaExceeded",\n
> "message": "Provisioning of resource(s) for container service
> testingdelete in resource group testingdelete failed. Message:
> Operation could not be completed as it results in exceeding approved
> Total Regional Cores quota. Additional details - Deployment Model:
> Resource Manager, Location: eastus2, Current Limit: 10, Current Usage:
> 10, Additional Required: 6, (Minimum) New Limit Required: 16. Submit a
> request for Quota increase at
> https://aka.ms/ProdportalCRP/?#create/Microsoft.Support/Parameters/%7B%22subId%22:********************************************************************************************************************************
> by specifying parameters listed in the ‘Details’ section for
> deployment to succeed. Please read more about quota limits at
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/regional-quota-requests..
> Details: "\n }. Details: "}]}

How to cleanup the old details which are left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have deleted the resource group, and it has completed OK then this should not be using your core quota. If there is nothing else in your sub using the core quota then you would need to raise a support ticket to get that resolved.

However, the easiest solution is just to raise the quota. You can do this by raising a  "Service and Subscriptions Limits" support requests (it is free) and indicating what quota you need increasing. Generally this is completed within a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks Sam, but for testing purpose we need to spinup multiple clusters and delete them later in the next few days. But I guess, if it is left like this in the background, then it might exceed the increased limit also

Comment: I have never had a deleted cluster retain quota once deleted, so if it is then this is a bug. However, given that you won't be billed for it then it won't be an issue for you. Just request a quota increase for a more reasonable limit (say 100 cores) and move on.

Comment: Thank you, I followed these steps to increase the limit. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/195003/databricks-cluster-error-code-operationnotallowed.html